# Can't get correct number of populated places for a place

Tags: api

I am trying to get a number of populated places for example for Andorra since it is a small number.  Here is a geonames site with 10 places:

http://www.geonames.org/AD/largest-cities-in-andorra.html

But if I do this query:

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PPL&username=genadinik&country=AD&style=full&maxRows=100

Only 4 out of the results have population.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a more accurate way of getting populated cities there?

Thanks!

Comment: The Data is only available for a few towns and cities - even Wolfram|Alpha is limited http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/countries/andorra/xy/p0/k6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The population count is simply not in the database (even though it is listed as a "populated place"). When no population count is available, you can see the XML tag:

```
<population/>
```

For example, see the edit form for [Sant Joan de Caselles](http://www.geonames.org/3039166/sant-joan-de-caselles.html):
[image: GeoNames]

Comment: thanks - is there maybe a better place to get populations of populated places?

Comment: This could be difficult to track down for remote pockets of the world

Comment: Actually I just realized my query could be wrong as it didn't even retrieve some of the biggest cities in Andorra.  So something bigger is out of whack.  Could I do something with the query to make it more correct and actually get Andorra cities like Santa Coloma and Saint Julia.

Comment: I'm not sure how to `ORDER BY population` using the web API, except to [download a snapshot](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/AD.zip) and load it to a local database to perform a specific query.

Comment: unless Andorra has a census of population and publishes the results there is probably no way to get this information. My guess would be they use a register of population instead of a census.

Answer (score 3):

If you need populations by town in Andorra you can get them from http://www.estadistica.ad/serveiestudis/web/banc_dades4.asp?lang=4&codi_tema=2&codi_divisio=16&codi_subtemes=8 which I found by examining the footnotes on the Andorra Wikipedia page.